# Is it possible to redirect to the same JSP page from a Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

A JSP page named `Test.jsp` is mapped to the following Servlet.

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/TestServlet"})
public final class TestServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin_side/Test.jsp").forward(request, response);
       response.sendRedirect("TestServlet");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

This Servlet is mapped to a JSP page `Test.jsp`. The `doGet()` method is invoked, when a URL like `http://localhost:8080/Assignment/TestServlet` is entered in the address bar.

The request can be forwarded to the given URL as commented out. Is it possible to redirect to the same JSP page, `Test.jsp`?

If an attempt is made to do so, Google Chrome complains,

> This webpage has a redirect loop

It can however, redirect to other pages under `WEB-INF/admin_side`.

Comment: Please show us, by showing us how in the code or configuration you did that, what you mean by "the servlet is mapped to the JSP", and "the JSP is mapped to the servlet". A foward is not a redirect. A redirect is not a forward. Currently, in the code you posted, you get a redirect loop because the servlet redirects to itself.

Comment: I don't have any configurations in `web.xml` for this Servlet.

Comment: So, except the WebServlet annotation which maps the servlet to the path /TestServlet, you don't have any mapping of the JSP to the servlet, and any mapping of the servlet to the JSP. So now, what's your question, and what do you want to achieve? Forwarding to anyJSP would work fine. The redirect loop you get from Chrome is caused by the fact that you're not forwarding to anything. Instead, the servlet redirect to itself.

Comment: I would like to redirect instead to avoid duplicate form submissions, the PRG design pattern, if it is possible to redirect to the same Servlet.

Comment: Handle POST and GET differently. Right now, they are both redirecting. 
`GET->REDIRECT->GET->REDIRECT->...` loop.

Comment: +1 to Sotirios. PRG means Post-Redirect-Get. Not Get-Redirect-Get.

Comment: I need to forward from `doGet()` and redirect from `doPost()`. Got it. Confused because of a common method handling both `GET` and `POST`. Thanks all. May someone please answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern works like so: a client sends a POST request, your server handles it and responds with a redirect, ie. a response with a 302 status code and `Location` header to the appropriate URI. The client makes a GET request to that URI.

Currently, your server is redirecting on both GET and POSTS requests. What's worse is that your GET is redirecting to the same URI that it is handling, creating the redirect loop you are seeing.

Change your Servlet implementation so that the POST sends a redirect, but the GET actually serves up a normal 200 response with HTML, AJAX, etc.